# 'CASE' expression whether to apply a WHERE condition to a query or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to accomplish something like the code below inside a stored procedure

```
    Select * from TABLE1 
       CASE WHEN @SPParameter != 0 THEN        -- if @SPParameter equals 0 then apply the where condition
          WHERE Table1Column = @SPParameter    -- apply a where condition
       END
```

This query's goal is to select all rows from `TABLE1` if `@SPParameter` is equal to zero, otherwise filter rows from `TABLE1` if `@SPParameter` is not equal to zero.

Obviously the query above would throw an error message since the syntax is incorrect. Is this possible? Or is an `if else` statement the only way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using `OR` condition like this way

```
WHERE (@SPParameter = 0 OR Table1Column = somevalue)
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a more clarified context.

Comment: Yes, `WHERE (@SPParameter = 0 OR Table1Column = somevalue)` might work well.

Comment: Well, you _can_ have a case expression in the WHERE clause, but you shouldn't.

Comment: From my point of view, use `OR` much to be more simple and clarify.

Comment: This solved my problem by using `where @SPParameter = 0 OR Table1Column = @SPParameter`

Answer (score 2):

Just use simple boolean logic<sup>1</sup>:

```
Select * from TABLE1 
   WHERE @SPParameter != 0 OR Table1Column = somevalue
```

`CASE` is an *expression*. It computes a *value*. It doesn't arbitrarily rearrange the parse tree of the statement it appears in.

---

<sup>1</sup>It'll be slightly more complex if we have to deal with `NULL`s but I've ignored them for now.

Comment: I've updated my question with a more clarified context.

Comment: Maybe `WHERE (@SPParameter = 0 OR Table1Column = somevalue)` instead. Because according to the OP, `@SPParameter != 0` will be applied

Comment: @Phong - the original question (and the comments still) specify that the `Table1Condition` should only be checked if `@SPParameter` is `0`, which is what my logic still applies. I don't know why the OP's started editing their question to reverse bits of logic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry for the late edits. I just added more clarification to my question so that my point will be clearer

Answer (score 1):

You try using case in where something like below:

```
 Select * from TABLE1 
 where Table1Column = case when @SPParameter = 0 then @SPParameter else @SPParameter  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, JobType
FROM   EMP
WHERE  1 = CASE

          WHEN JobType = 'VC' THEN 1
          WHEN JobType = 'HR' THEN 1
          WHEN JobType = 'DEV' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END;
```

Above example CASE returns if jobtype present in table then it will be return the Name and JobType.

Comment: I would use an `WHERE JobType IN ('VC', 'HR', 'DEV')` here.  Also needs to take into account whether the OP wants to apply the `WHERE` clause (when `@SPParameter = [0|1]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TABLE1
          WHERE Table1Column = CASE 
          WHEN @SPParameter != 0 THEN  @SPParameter  
       END;
```

Here `WHERE` condition gets the value from the `CASE` statement, if `@SPParameter` is not equals zero, which means the value is present THEN it will be return the `@SPParameter` value.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you're getting at with this one - you're comparing the `TableColumn` with `@SPParameter` if `@SPParameter` is anything other than 0 (zero)?  What happens if it *is* 0 (zero)?  Wouldn't it be easier just to say: `WHERE TableColumn = @SPParameter AND @SPParameter > 0`, simplifying to `WHERE TableColumn > 0`?  *(Assuming that all values are greater than 0 (zero))*