# How to apply DRY principle to SELECT in SQL procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a number of SQL Stored Procedures querying the same table with different arguments and `WHERE` clauses. How can I define the columns in SELECT in a single place so they are shared across all similar procedures? Can you also share the performance or maintainability implication please?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Metadata_GetById]
  @Id int = 0
AS
  SELECT M.Id,
         M.Name
         -- A long list of column selections
  FROM   dbo.Metadata M
  WHERE  M.Id = @Id;
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Metadata_GetByName]
  @Name nvarchar(200)
AS
  SELECT M.Id,
         M.Name
         -- A long list of column selections
  FROM   dbo.Metadata M
  WHERE  M.Name = @Name;
```

Comment: Consider `where (M.Id = @Id or @id is null) and ...`, in one common procedure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['CASE' expression whether to apply a WHERE condition to a query or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484754/case-expression-whether-to-apply-a-where-condition-to-a-query-or-not)

Comment: `CREATE VIEW`  and maintain the columns list in it and then `select *` from the view.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin  That still leaves you with needing to track where the results of the sproc are ending up; not every destination may want or need or be able to handle any column changes.

Comment: @JimmyWu . . . Why use stored procedures at all?  Just query the table directly.  Or, if the query is a little complicated, use a view.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I define the columns in SELECT in a single place so they are shared across all similar procedures?

In short, you can't.  SQL is not a procedural programming language, but a set based declarative one.  Consequently, principles like DRY don't really hold up in the SQL world.

Your only option here is to follow @jarlh's advice and to make a single procedure that allows passing of several parameters to filter on different columns all within the same procedure.  This will come with it's own issues though, as you now have a monolith procedure that you will need to monitor and maintain as your database grows and develops.

Comment: "Consequently, principles like DRY don't really hold up in the SQL world" - to an extent, _yes_ - but can we agree that SQL's verboseness and inability to reference column expressions in the same query level is _downright user-hostile_. There should be no need to repeat the exact same sub-expression over and over, but we're _forced to_: string/text-processing in SQL is the worst: Whenever I need to use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` I find myself repeating expressions over and over. (The only alternative is to use an outer query or a CTE, both of which balloon a query's size).

Comment: @Dai agreed. To me, being unable to easily implement DRY principles is the mark of a bad language

Comment: I would say that it is less a case of being hostile or a bad language, but rather people being unfamiliar with set based logic and/or expecting too much of the language.  Worrying about having to 'balloon a query's size' also isn't all that relevant in a declarative language provided you aren't doing anything silly.  And if your query is so long it is unmanageable, that should really be a wake up call to refactor your solution rather than to complain about the language.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create one sp with 2 params along with default value is null.

After that, you can use boolean logic like `@Id is null or M.Id = @Id`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Metadata_GetBy]
  @Id int = null,
  @Name nvarchar(200) = null
AS
  SELECT M.Id,
         M.Name
         -- A long list of column selections
  FROM   dbo.Metadata M
  WHERE  (@Id is null or M.Id = @Id) 
         and (@Name is null or M.Name = @Name);
```

**How to use**

```
exec stp_Metadata_GetBy @Id = 1 -- if you want to query by ID

exec stp_Metadata_GetBy @Name = 'abc' -- if you want to query by Name
```

Looks like this one ['CASE' expression whether to apply a WHERE condition to a query or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484754/case-expression-whether-to-apply-a-where-condition-to-a-query-or-not/60484790#60484790)

Comment: @Jimmy Wu Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: This solution makes the procedure difficult to understand what exactly it is filtering. Not clear to callers how arguments are used together or independently by looking at the procedure signature.

Comment: I don't think so. As you want to apply DRY principle. So this way help you remove redundant duplication code. Otherwise, you can create View then get from it instead stored procedure.

Comment: To anyone familiar with the language it's quite obvious how it works. It's just standard boolean logic.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using such pattern to work with optional parameters at all. It affects performance terribly due to parameters sniffing and will work unpredictably related to what parameter was received on the first run.

Comment: I was incorrect. It would be unpredictable if the parameters were not optional. With optional parameters it will be fairly predictable - always table/clustered index scan whatever other indexes are created on the table.